# Can't find the .bitmonero directory to set up the blockchain.raw file in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: monerod, blockchain-import

I changed from windows to Ubuntu 17.10 Linux. I'm totally new on it. I've been learning how to work with the terminal, and I have already downloaded my old windows blockchain.raw file located in the my download files. When I try to open the monerod.exe, nothing happens. I open up the GUI and it starts from scratch. I opened

> monero-blockchain-import

And the monero-blockchain-import.log says the following:

> lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:2674  WARNING: batch transaction mode already enabled, but asked to enable batch mode
>   2017-12-03 23:13:33.979     7f1e57c56f00    FATAL   bcutil  src/blockchain_utilities/blockchain_import.cpp:229  bootstrap file not found: "/home/lh1008/.bitmonero/export/blockchain.raw"

I went to my "home directory" and can't find anywhere the .bitmonero export directory. Through the terminal I ran the command to prompt monero-blockchain-import to the download directory where I have the blockchain.raw file but the terminal gave me an answer that "monero-blockchain-import doesn't exist". Have tried several times, read the manual for help but I can't find my error. I can run from scratch the node but I also want to learn how to do it properly. I will really appreciate any help.

Can anyone help?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put this file anywhere, you just need to add `--input-file XX` and put the file and its path instead of XX, eg:

`monero-blockchain-import --input-file $HOME/blockchain.raw`

As for  "monero-blockchain-import doesn't exist" errors, this is unrelated, and just means monero-blockchain-import is not in your PATH environment variable. Either add its directory to your PATH, or give the whole path to it (either relative or absolute), eg:

`./monero-blockchain-import --input-file $HOME/blockchain.raw`

if it's in the current directory, or maybe:

`build/release/bin/monero-blockchain-import --input-file $HOME/blockchain.raw`

if you've just built it.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find the .bitmonero directory in the /home folder and was not aware that "." folders are hidden. So I searched for help in the Ubuntu community and found this answer [How to show a hidden file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232649/how-to-show-a-hidden-file). 
It was easy, stand in the home directory and put this command:

> cmd/ctrl + H

Then, the .bitmonero directory showed up.

This answer might help anyone. :)